# Is there a way to "sign" an HTTP Post in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, security

I have users with accounts on Site A. Site A has been around a long time, and it's expensive (but not impossible) to change its code.

Site B (I'm working on it now!) hosts a brand new web app for the customers of Site A. The Site B app has a list of the usernames from Site A, and maintains preferences and other information about each of those users that pertains to their usage of Site B. Site A and B are different platforms. I think Site A is coldfusion, and Site B is ASP.NET MVC.

I want users to be able to click a link in Site A that logs them into the app on Site B. I was thinking it might work like this:

0) If user tries to go straight to Site B, they just get redirected to Site A to be authenticated.

1) User logs into Site A.

2) Once logged into Site A, they can click a link that takes them to Site B. I was thinking I would do an HTTP Post from Site A to Site B with the username, so Site B knows who is logging in and how to render their pages based on their preferences.

Of course, I don't want any Joe Schmoe to be able to do an HTTP POST to Site B with a username and get to be logged in as that user.

So I was wondering if, using certificates or something, I could make it so Site B is able to know for certain that the POST really came from Site A. Do I need / Can I use certificates for this? Maybe Site A can somehow "sign" its post so Site B can know for sure the post came from Site A?

Or could just a password be enough, where Site A posts a password over SSL along with the username that only Site B knows?

I'm also open to the idea of Site A posting the username and a GUID to Site B, which Site B would then "ask" Site A via a web service if this is indeed a recent and valid GUID that did in fact originate at Site A, but that seems like a trip I can eliminate.

I hope that is descriptive enough. Please feel free to have me explain more. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be..

- User signs into site A.
- Site A creates a guid that is associated with this user but will expire in 5 seconds or some short time frame.
- The user is redirected to siteB?UserID=SomId&ConfirmationId=Some Guid
- Site B calls a web service on Site A, passing the UserID and Guid and checks to see if this is a valid redirect.  (The web service just returns a true or a false).

This solves your issue of trust, as site B is explicitly querying site A, so site B KNOWS that it is using Site A for authentication, and not just blindly trusting that the confirmation is coming from a redirect from site A.

Also, a Guid is unique enough that it's unlikely to be guessed by hackers, and finally, the expiration makes it so that if a hacker DOES guess the guid, it will likely have expired by the time it's been guessed.

Of course, you'll want this all done over SSL.

Comment: Cool... this was my last idea (in my second-to-last paragraph). I think it's the most secure idea so far, but I was just hoping to get rid of that web service call. It's pretty lightweight, so if I can't get rid of it, I'll live! Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I did give you an answer you had already provided.  Sorry.

Comment: That's ok! The fact that someone with 4000 rep conceived it independently provides me with much-needed validation. :)

Comment: Guid's are unique but not cryptographically secure. This is unwise.

Comment: Silky, I am not sure what you mean by that. If you have a better answer, can you please post it?